# Добавление в скомпилированный проект зависящих DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Есть ли возможность при компиляции проекта, чтобы в папку со скомпилированным проектом добавлялись DLL файлы, от которых зависит проект
Visual Studio 2020

Comment: Можно добавить команды копирования в Post-build шаг.

Answer (score 0):

От которых зависит или которые зависят? Зависящие dll добавляются в контекстном меню проекта(ПКМ по проекту) -> Add -> Project reference. Чтобы выбрать локальные библиотеки выбери в окне добавления ссылок Browse и поставь галочки если библиотека в том же решении, если не в том же то через проводник(кнопка открытия файлов справа снизу)
UPD. Это работает и для шарпов и для плюсов, во всех версиях вижуалки, даже в самой новой и 2012

Comment: Вы с C# случаем не перепутали?

Comment: Так для плюсов то же самое, там такое же окно. Буквально сейчас перепроверил.(vs pre 2022)

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ну во-первых самая новая версия - это 2022, и окна там разные, кнопки Browse в варианте окна для С++ вообще нет. И само добавление ссылок на другие проекты может делать не то, что нужно.

Comment: Я обновил ответ, там я везде буквально проверил, все есть. В вижуалке меняется только дизайн и InteliSense с годами

Comment: Если вы видите кнопку Browse, то значит это проект C#.

Comment: Я перепроверил с плюсами, там можно добавить и скомпилированные dll и библиотеки и проекты в решении